# Import CSV files with CYPHER

Tags: neo4j

I know this question is recurring, but I can not come to an end on my own, I need your help.

Load csv with headers from,

```
"file:D:\Treina1_Neo4j.csv" as airports
CREATE (a1:Airport {label:airports.label, city:airports.city, state:airports.state })
```

and it returns the following error.

```
Invalid input 'T': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', UTF16 or UTF32 (line 2, column 10 (offset: 36))
""file:D:\Treina1_Neo4j.csv" as airports"
```

Where I was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First note the instructions in https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/ and in particular the importance of the **dbms.directories.import** parameter. Secondly, your statement should start as follows :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:D:/Treina1_Neo4j.csv" AS as airports
```

Note **the direction of the slash**.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Dear Tom Geudens, your suggestion was very well received, helped and much but not resolved. The new error message now is:
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError
URI is not hierarchical

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, though I considered the solution to be of poor quality.

load csv with headers from "file:///neo4j-airport-csv-raw.csv" as airports
CREATE (a1:Airport {label:airports.label, city:airports.city, state:airports.state })

**I put the .csv file inside the import directory of NEO4J.**

Comment: As Tom hinted above, if you set `dbms.directories.import=""` it should allow you to load CSV files from anywhere on your file system